# xindy: merge-rule merges to the wrong entry

Tags: indexing, sorting, xindy

Consider the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.xdy}
(merge-rule "More, Thomas" "Morus, Thomas")
\end{filecontents*}
\def\xindyopt{-C utf8  -M test -M texindy}
\makeindex[program=truexindy,options=\xindyopt]
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
Test
\index{More, Thomas}
\newpage
New Test
\index{Morus, Thomas}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

In my understanding this should to lead one entry `Morus, Thomas`, but it does the opposite.

[image]

When I change the order and put `\index{Morus, Thomas}` before `\index{More, Thomas}`, both entries are printed under `Morus, Thomas`. I don't understand why this happens. I thought the merge-rule would regulate which entry gets sorted where.

**EDIT:** I just realized that the entry is actually sorted correctly, it's just displayed wrong. If you add additional index entries, for example `\index{mort}, you see that displayed entry ´More, Thomas` is sorted under `Morus, Thomas`. So both entries are sorted correctly, they are just displayed the wrong way.

Comment: After asking this question on the `xindy` mailing list, the answer seems to be that this is a shortcoming of `xindy` and that there is no way around it.